# Gradle exclude SLF4J from Spring

Tags: spring, logging, gradle, log4j, spring-boot

Well, the following code works but it does not really look good. I have a Spring Boot project and I want to exclude SLF4J because I would like to use Log4j2 instead.

Does anyone know how to improve the code?

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")
    providedRuntime("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can e.g. try:

```
dependencies {
    [
        "org.springframework:spring-context",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb",
    ].each { dep ->
        compile(dep) {
            exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
            exclude module: "logback-classic"
        }
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")
    runtime("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

Comment: Accepted your answer since this version looks much better than my version, thanks for this. Is runtime equal to providedRuntime?

Comment: No. These are different configurations. `runtime` comes from `java` plugin while `providedRuntime` from `war`: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html. I didn't know your configuration so I just replaced `providedRuntime` with `runtime` to make it work.

Comment: Why is the jar file still present in gradle cache, when its not showing up in gradle dependencies, And hence when i start my project it still shows binding issues, even though gradle dependency list has no reference to log back ... any idea ??